# Create a Java POJO class for a Complex Json hierarchy

Tags: java, json

i want to know how to create a Java Pojo class for a complex Json like this one.

```
{
    "glossary" : {
        "title" : "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv" : {
            "title" : "S",
            "GlossList" : {
                "GlossEntry" : {
                    "ID" : "SGML",
                    "SortAs" : "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm" : "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym" : "SGML",
                    "Abbrev" : "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef" : {
                        "para" : "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso" : ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee" : "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I found this example [here](http://json.org/example)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. What did you try ? What is your problem ? How does having a "complex JSON hierarchy" differ from a simple one ?

Comment: It seems that you would need at least five classes: Glossary, GlossaryDiv, GlossaryList, GlossaryEntry and GlossaryDef.

Comment: thank you Maurice, and yes i think that i should create a class for every Json Object as simple as that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use one of online services to generate POJOs from JSON, e.g. I'd prefer to use [this one](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Simply copy your JSON, select "Source type" as JSON and press preview or jar. In case of jar just unpack it with any zip/unzip program and copy files in your project. That's it.

Comment: this service is very useful, thank you.